# Return type of a function returning a lambda function

Tags: types, f#

I'm trying to wrap my head around the return type of the function `foo` below. `foo` returns a lambda function which takes a function `f` of type `int -> int` and an `int` `y` and evaluates to an `int`.

> How come then that the type isn't  `int -> int -> int -> int` ?

Writing the return type of `foo` as any other than `(int -> int) -> (int -> int)`, Visual Studio complains.

```ml
let next (x:int) = x + 1

let pass_x (x:int) : (int -> int) -> (int -> int) = 
    fun (f:int -> int) -> 
        fun (y:int) -> 
            f (y + x)

let foo (x : int) : (int -> int) -> (int -> int) =
    fun (f : int -> int) (y:int) ->
        ((next 1) |> pass_x) f y
```

In contrast `pass_x` also returns a lambda function, but this time the return type of `pass_x` agrres with the argument types and the return type of the returned lambda function.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write a type of a function without any parentheses, it is interpreted as a function written in a curried form, i.e. a function that takes the first argument and returns a function taking further arguments.

This means that `int -> int -> int -> int` means the same thing as:

```
int -> (int -> (int -> int))
```

This is different from the return type of `foo` which is:

```
(int -> int) -> (int -> int)
```

Or, written without the sectond pair of parentheses, which is optional:

```
(int -> int) -> int -> int
```

The difference is that:

- The former is a function that takes `int`, returns a function taking another `int` which returns a function taking one more `int` and returns an `int` - equivalently, this is a function taking three integers and returning another one.
- The latter is a function that takes a function (`int -> int`) and returns a function taking an `int` and returning an `int`.

In other words, one is a function taking three numbers whereas the other is a function taking a function and a number.

Comment: Thanks great answer! So they key is that `(int -> int) -> (int -> int)` is equivalent to `(int -> int) -> int -> int` where the latter agrees with my understanding of the type of the lambda function returned from `foo`.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to understand this is that the type arrow is right associative. So `int -> int -> int` means `int -> (int -> int)`, not `(int -> int) -> int`.